# Can we use Kstream with Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-kafka-streams

Can we use Kstream with Spark?

Is it a recommended approach, or using Spark Streaming is a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we use Kstream with Spark?

Sure.

> Is it a recommended approach

Not really (if at all).

> using the Spark Streaming is a better solution.

"Better" begs for another question "In what scenarios?"

---

Kafka Streams is a library and as such can be used anywhere a library could be used in an application, incl. Spark applications. In that sense, it is possible, but not really of much help IMHO.

Kafka Streams is simply a bunch of threads that use Consumer and Producer APIs to transform records. That's the Kafka data format in Spark Structured Streaming exactly.

Kafka Streams applications are deployed as standalone Java applications (e.g. Docker containers in k8s). The same is also possible with Spark Structured Streaming (with Spark on Kubernetes).

See no real benefit using both in a single application but would love proven wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Kafka Streams "with" Spark Streaming.

For example, Kafka Streams would consume singular records from a topic, which you would map to a single element Spark RDD with a parallelize call? You're then not using Spark Streaming libraries

Other way, you consume RDD from Spark Streaming. Then, there's no way to get that data into a Kafka Streams topology...

So, they are not compatible to be used "together".

---

You can, alternatively, deploy a Spark application that may "include" Kafka Streams topologies, for example if you were wanting a KTable as part of each RDD action, but this is no different answer than any embedding Kafka Streams in any other JVM application. Just keep in mind that non-streaming Spark executors are short lived and ephemeral and any Kafka Streams state wouldn't be stored with Spark checkpoints

Besides that, if you use Kubernetes, for example as a Spark Scheduler, then you can deploy separate containers; one Kafka Streams app could consume or produce data into Spark Streaming, or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any supporting documentation or link material which proves that Kafka Streams and Spark Streams are not compatible to be used together.

Comment: Not sure why there would be since they are completely separate Apache projects. Their deployment models are completely different. You run Spark code with spark-submit and Kafka Streams just as a JAR. Spark has its own checkpoint management that relies optionally on filesystem and Kafka Streams always depends on Kafka... Etc, etc. How would you expect to use them together?

Comment: _"Kafka Streams and Spark (Streaming) are not compatible to be used together."_ is certainly incorrect. You can instantiate all the necessary pieces of a Kafka Streams application in a Spark Structured Streaming app. They both are gonna work fine. Kafka Streams would simply "consume" some of the Spark driver's resources and that's it.

Comment: @Jacek You can't join topics together using the two, for example. Spark wouldn't be able to access internal Kafka Streams topics, if needed, and Spark doesn't use anything but String/Bytes serialization... So, there's multiple reasons they _shouldn't_ be used together. Didn't mean to say they can't be

Comment: There was nothing about _"You can't join topics together using the two"_, wasn't there?